# Selecting the last record of yesterday and all records of today in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I know it's possible to get yesterday records, most common way using `SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)` or maybe simply use `CURDATE() - 1` and use `LIMIT` and `ORDER` to retrieve the last record of yesterday.

But here, I need to get the last record of yesterday in the first row and the rest will be all records of today. I need to run this within single query.

For example, I have following records in one of my table:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| value    | created_at                          |
--------------------------------------------------
| 70       | 1/1/2017                            |
| 300      | 1/1/2017                            |
| 100      | 1/1/2017                            |
| 235      | 1/2/2017                            |
| 45       | 1/2/2017                            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The `created_at` column is a timestamp, if today is 1/2/2017 (2th January 2017) then the result of the query should be:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| value    | created_at                          |
--------------------------------------------------
| 100      | 1/1/2017                            |
| 235      | 1/2/2017                            |
| 45       | 1/2/2017                            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

So far, I only able to retrieve the records of today with following query:
`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE created_at >= CURDATE();`

What query I need to accomplish this?

Comment: Last record is previous day or yesterday? sometime previous day can be day before yesterday when there is no transaction yesterday

Comment: Have you tried using `UNION`

Comment: Post some sample data and what you have tried so far

Comment: @sumit, it's yesterday, not previous day

Answer (score 1):

Hoping you have id as primary  key

```
select * from 
   (select 
     * 
    from 
    tbl 
    where date(created_at) =date(DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) 
    order by id desc limit 0,1
   )tmp 

  UNION 

  select * from tbl where date(created_at)=date(now())
```